# iOS | SDK | Privacy manifest file

Tags: ios, xcode, privacy-policy

I am having an iOS framework project and that will be distributed as XCFramework to the customers. I have couple of questions regarding the privacy manifest file which are going to be mandatory for app releases from Spring 2024. The below are my questions:

1. What if our SDK does not collect any data and it does some simple logics. Do we still required to provide manifest file? What keys has to be added in this case? Simply "NSPrivacyTracking" as "No"?
2. What if our SDK access the CoreBluetooth and Camera? Do we need to add "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes" in Privacy manifest file?

Thanks in advance.